# C# ASP.NET Open a new windows and redirecting in button click event

Tags: c#, response.redirect

How can i redirect to another page and open a new window in one button click?

```
protected void ASPxButton_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         //do other stuff

         if (oSoins.DEVENIR_ECVAC_PAR != 0)
         {
             string AdrUrl = "Print_DosSoin.aspx?SoinId=" + Soin_Id;
             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", AdrUrl));
          }


          Response.Redirect("DossierSoin_Liste.aspx");
       }
       catch (ThreadAbortException) {/* do nothing, it might be a response.Redirect exception */}
       catch (Exception excThrown)
       {
          lbl_err.Text = excThrown.Message;
          if (excThrown.InnerException != null) lbl_err.Text += "-->" + excThrown.InnerException.Message;
          string TempMsg = "DosSoin Fiche " + Appel_ID + "-- ASPxButton_save_Click -->" + lbl_err.Text;
          Outils.SendingEmail(TempMsg);
        }
```

With the script above it's redirecting but does not open a new window.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: That cannot work: you're registering a startupscript in your page, then you're executing (redirecting to) another one.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your javascript to the following:

```
string script = default(string)

if (oSoins.DEVENIR_ECVAC_PAR != 0)
{
    string AdrUrl = "Print_DosSoin.aspx?SoinId=" + Soin_Id;
    script = string.Format("window.open('{0}'); ", AdrUrl);
}

script += " window.location.href = 'DossierSoin_Liste.aspx';";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", script, true);
```

This will create a new window then redirect on the client.